# Hibernate: how to annotate Collection<Object> to allow search

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, jpa-2.0, hibernate-search

Say I have a model A like this:

```
@Embeddable
class A {
    @Field
    private String name;
    @Field
    private Boolean editable;
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private B bObject;
}
```

where, B is, say

```
@Embeddable
class B {
    @Field
    private int intValue;
    @Field
    private boolean boolValue;
}
```

Now, I have a class C,

```
@Entity
class C {

    //How to annotate this to enable search like setOfA.name="searchQuery", or setOfA.bObject.intValue=5
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<A> setOfA;
}
```

I see that I can create custom Bridge, but can't figure out what the Bridge should do, specially to enable search like setOfA.bObject.intValue = 5.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an working exemple:

```
@ElementCollection
@Field(name="listStringField")
@FieldBridge(impl=BuiltinIterableBridge.class)//ListStringBridge.class)
public List<String> getListString(){
    return listString;
}
```

- **@Field(name...)** defines a searchable field.
- **@FieldBridge** allows to my list to be searchable, but for that, you have to precise what bridge you want to use. The bridge is what will make the field indexable.
- **BuiltinIterableBridge**, this bridge is natively present in packages of Hibernate Search. All you have to do, is just to use it !
- **ListStringBridge**. A bridge that i have created who extends IterableBridge. You can write your own.

Answer (score 1):

use `@ContainedIn` over collection object like :

```
@ContainedIn
private Set<A> setOfA;
```

And use `@IndexedEmbedded` over other side like :

```
@Embeddable
class A {
    @Field
    private String name;
    @Field
    private Boolean editable;
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private B bObject;

    @OneToOne( cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE } )
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private C cObject; 
}
```

Comment: you can use OneToOne as per your requirment, this is just a sample.

Comment: Thanks Atul for the suggestion, I tried this, but getting `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for com.*.C, at table: C_setOfA, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(setOfA.forC)]` exception.

Comment: That is of hibernate mapping error, not related with hibernate search

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` so it's a properly mapped association by terms of JPA. Then add `@IndexedEmbedded` to enable full-text search through Hibernate Search.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar for the suggestion. Actually I was using @ElementCollection as A is an embeddable object. With `@ElementCollection @IndexedEmbedded private Set<A> setOfA` only one object from the setOfA is getting indexed (I think others are being overwritten).